# Tracking user's activities and give suggestion

Tags: asp.net, user-tracking

I would like to implement a suggestion mechanism like Amazon. When users browser my ASP.Net page, their activities are tracked and we can analyze their behaviors to give advertisements, suggestions, etc
Could you please help me some articles, books or libraries,... ?

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm... you should look something about ai to prepare frames to divide your customers... maybe [here](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~jxb/iai.html) you could find something.

With enought data, I would prepare some frames and then, when an new product arrives, check in which frame does it fall, and recommend it to the people whose interests overlay...

Comment: The usual way of doing this is by studying the historic information you have, so that you can prepare the frames of likeness.
Then, if I purchase something situated on the frame "SciFi" you will have a X% possibilities of me liking other products on the same frame and (maybe) Y% possibilities of me liking the frame "Fantasy"
The more info you have at the beggining, and the more exhaustive your calculations to prepare the frames, the more precise the recommendation will be.